# what does condition number of not complete power of 10 imply?

Tags: numerical-linear-algebra, condition-number

so if I have a condition number like $5*10^9$, does this mean that I might lose a upward of 9 significant figures, or 10? I know that if it is $10^9$ then it will lose up to 9 but not sure for condition numbers that are not power of 10.

Comment: I have never heard about a correspondance between condition number $\approx 10^9$ and "loss of $9$ decimal places". Besides, loss with respect to what ?

Comment: um, so I think that assuming that the relative error of input is 2^(-52) in double precision, if conditioning number* relative error of input>1, that would mean that our relative error of output is greater than 1 which will make us loss all precision-- I am not sure about these terminologies too, its just that our professor uses it.

Comment: It is rule of thumb that can have a certain validity around $10^9$, who knows... but beware not to extend it by linearity (e.g., condition number $\approx 10^3 \ \implies$ loss of 3 decimal places...which would be quite false).

Comment: In fact, I just saw [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/675661) which in fact acks up what your teacher said...